# Not getting a response object from my third party API call express routes node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, promise, backend

I am struggling with an API-call, since my response object is always undefined. Every console.log(res) returns undefined. This wouldn't be a problem, but I need to call res.json() to send to front-end. Unfortunately, I can't call send() on an undefined object. Here is my API call, I added some comments to explain.

```
  router.route("/run").post((req: any, res: any) => {
  data.source_code = req.body.code;
  axios({
    url: "http://35.205.20.238/submissions",
    method: "POST",
    data: data,
  })
    .then(async (req: any, res: any) => {
      //first call generates a token
      await new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, 1000)); // 3 sec
      //after waiting, use the token to get the res.data.stdout which is 
      //what I want to send to frontend using res.send()
      axios
        .get("http://35.205.20.238/submissions/" + req.data.token)
        .then((req: any, res: any) => {
          console.log(req);
          if (!req) {
            console.log("no output");
          }
          finalOutput = req.data.stdout;
          console.log(req.data.stdout);
        });
    })
    .catch((err: Error) => console.log(err));
});
```

How can I solve this? Is it possible to send data to front-end with an undefined response-object? Or have I messed up the promise-chaining?

Maybe this API is for front-end only.

(please ignore the type-definitions on req and res for now)

Comment: I don't understand why you're telling it to wait 3 seconds.

Comment: because the API is an online code judge which requires you to wait. The submissions (first http post call) get put in a short queue.

oh and the comment is wrong, it's only 1sec

Comment: Ok. Well, it looks like you're redeclaring req and res in each `.then()` block, which I think is the root of your problem. The original res and req will be available at those scopes if you don't do that, and the results of each axios call should be the input variables of the `.then()` calls.

Comment: no, it was my environment variables which weren't recognized by Heroku. although I agree the way I handle the API call is suspect. thanks for taking your time to help me though :)

Comment: actually, it's still happening :( just a little later

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My problem was that Heroku wasn't recognising my envoirement variables. It just showed up on Chrome as a CORS-error, but it was actually Heroku all along. Lesson learnt.